# Calling static functions from other class functions isnt working

Tags: php

I am trying to achieve the goal of static configuration data, where I can grab config items from an array at any file I want. I have made the functions static and it still is saying class could not be found? I am pretty new to PHP so help me out...

Index.php:

```
include(ROOT . '/application/library/yoda/settings.class.php');

if (class_exists('Settings')) {
    Settings::setPublic('testpublic', 'This is a test setting for the public category.');
}
```

Settings class:

```
class Settings
{
    static private $protectedSettings = array(); // For DB / passwords etc
    static private $publicSettings = array(); // For all public strings such as meta stuff for site

    /*public function __construct() {
        $this->protectedSettings = array();
        $this->publicSettings = array();
    }*/

    public static function getProtected($key) {
        return isset(self::$protectedSettings[$key]) ? self::$protectedSettings[$key] : false;
    }

    public static function getPublic($key) {
        return isset(self::$publicSettings[$key]) ? self::$publicSettings[$key] : false;
    }

    public static function setProtected($key,$value) {
        self::$protectedSettings[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function setPublic($key,$value) {
        self::$publicSettings[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Where the error displays is in the code below... when I call showConfig()

```
class template {

    public function showConfig() {
        exit(Settings::getPublic('testpublic'));
    }
}
```

When calling showConfig() it displays the error below...

> Fatal error: Class 'Settings' not found

Comment: check include path weather its correct or not. it's working for me

Comment: Make sure that the Settings class is visible and included to your template class, you can do this by throwing an include_once 'path/to/Settings.php' above your template class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including the Settings class file in the file that has the template class.

Other than that the code looks good and should be working.

Comment: Is there any better way to include it other than just using the include() function?

Comment: You could setup an autoloader (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) or use one of the existing autoloaders. If you are just starting out it will probably be easier to just include or require_once it at the top of the files you use it in.